# React Query Firestore Data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I am trying to query data in my redux store to get data from firebase but I am getting undefined
Where am I going wrong? Please can someone help me . Is the way I am querying the data wrong or?

The House Class:

```
class House {
    constructor( 
        id,
        name,
        imageUri,
        method
    ){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.imageUri = imageUri
        this.method = method;
    
    }
    
}

export default House
```

Redux Store:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import House from '../../models/House'

const initialState = {
    favourites :[],
}
const FavsReducer = (state=initialState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case TOGGLE_FAVOURITE:
                let myfav = new House()
                firebase.firestore()
                    .collection('Posts')
                    .where('postId', '==', action.houseId)
                    .get()
                    .then(snapshots => {
                        snapshots.docs.forEach(doc=>{
                            myfav = new House(
                                doc.data().id,
                                doc.data().name,
                                doc.data().image,
                                doc.data().method
                            )
                        })
                    })
                return {...state, favourites: state.favourites.concat(house)}
        default: 
            return state
    }
}
export default FavsReducer
```

When I `console.log` the `favourites` array

```
Array [
  House {
    "id": undefined,
    "imageUri": undefined,
    "method": undefined,
    "name": undefined,
  },
]
```

The firestore

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
firebase.firestore()
        .collection('Posts')
        .doc(action.houseId)
        .get()
        .then((docRef) => { console.log(docRef.data()) })
```

Comment: Thank you so much you're a life saver your answer helped. That worked. God bless you.

Comment: One more thing ,. how do i add the `docRef.data()` to a new array

Comment: You can declare a variable outside of the query, for example var arr=[] and in the then function you can use arr.push(docRef.data()). I don't know if I get your point

Comment: Okay so is the way I am returning it to my favourites array by concating correct or ?

Comment: Because this is a query so it not return the value immediately, just imagine that it like a timeout. You can take a look at this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126566/how-to-work-with-api-call-action-in-redux