# How to execute api call with redux?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm recently learn about react-redux. Now i'm bit stuck about how can i execute the `api call`.

Here is my action.ts

```
export const fetchEvent = () => async (
    dispatch: Dispatch
) => {
    dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.FETCH_EVENT_REQUEST });

    try {
        const response = await axios.get<EvenData[]>(
            `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/`
        );
        dispatch<FetchEventAction>({
            type: ActionTypes.FETCH_EVENT_SUCCESS,
            payload: response.data
        });

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.FETCH_EVENT_FAILURE, error });
    }
};
```

and here is my event list and this is where i want call the api call

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: ActionTypes) => ({});
const dispatchProps = {};

type Props = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> & typeof dispatchProps;

type State = {};

class EventList extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    componentDidMount() {
        // dispatch(fetchEvent());
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section>
                <p>{ }</p>
            </section>
        );

    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    dispatchProps
)(EventList);
```

So how can i make the api call ? inside my `componentDidMount`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126566/how-to-work-with-api-call-action-in-redux  Check out this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing the mapDispatchToProps , the one your are using is empty {}.

```
import {fetchEvent} from 'action.ts' // change to correct path

const mapStateToProps = (state: ActionTypes) => ({});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchEvent: () => {
      dispatch(fetchEvent())
    }
  };
};

type Props = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> & ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps>;

type State = {};

class EventList extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchEvent()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section>
                <p>{ }</p>
            </section>
        );

    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(EventList);
```

Comment: but i recommend to try using functional component and use redux hooks it is way easier and less confusing.

Comment: Addition to **SebMaz93** answer, I recommend to use [`redux-toolkit`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), instead of implementing by yourself. There are a lot of hooks that you can use them.